# MoveFile doesn't work if I have russian letters in file path

Tags: vbscript

`MoveFile` doesn't work if I have russian letters in file path, any way to fix that? If path doesn't have russian letters than all works fine.

Script gives me error - "Path not found"

My VBScript:

```
Set f = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If f.FileExists("C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Local\Temp\tempFile.exe") Then _
    f.MoveFile "C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Local\Temp\tempFile.exe", _
               "C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\СУППЕР ЗЛО\test.exe"
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get an error? What does it say?

Comment: It gives error 'Path not found''

Comment: Please post the complete exact error message in your question. Did you save the script as Unicode? Did you check that the destination folder actually exists?

Comment: I save file in UTF8. Thats russian letters problem, if i delete "СУППЕР ЗЛО" from path, that all work's like it should.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to save the file in **Unicode** format instead of UTF-8